# Why is this if-else statement not working?

Tags: python

So, if the person answers "nutella", it prints "That's correct!" How do I get it to say "You're wrong!" if they answer anything else.

```
nutella = input

input("What's the best food in the world?")

if nutella:

    print("That's correct!")

else: 

    print("You're wrong!")
```

Comment: The first 3 lines are completely wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, it seems you should look into `if` statements since you don't know how to use them yet, but this is how you do it, I'll try to explain as well

```
choice = input("What's the best food in the world?")
if choice == "Nutella":
    print("That's correct!")
else:
    print("You're wrong!")
```

So the first line assigns what the person types to the variable `choice` and then in the next line it checks if the value of the variable equals/is `"nutella"`, if it is it will print `"That's correct!"`, if it isn't it will print `"You're wrong!"`.

Answer (score 0):

The `if` statement in Python for a string is true whenever the string isn't empty. What you want is to compare the `nutella` variable with the expected string. Such as:

```
nutella = input("What's the best food in the world?")

if nutella == "nutella":
    print("That's correct!")
else: 
    print("You're wrong!")
```